# Инициализация структуры С и в С++

Tags: c++, c, структуры, инициализация

Есть структура вида

```
   typedef struct struct_name {
      struct another_struct_name {
         typefield1 field1;
         typefield2 field2;
      } const * field_name;
   } struct_name_t;

   typedef struct another_struct_name another_struct_name_t;
```

В Си данную структуру инициализирую например так

```
const another_struct_name_t some_an_s = {
   .field1 = value1,
   .field2 = value2 
}; 
const struct_name_t name = { .field_name = &some_an_s };
```

Всё работает... однако, на С++ аналогичная конструкция

```
const struct_name_t name = {&some_an_s};
```

a value of type "`const struct_name_t *`" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "`const struct_name::another_struct_name *`"

Если так

```
struct another_struct_name const* temp = {&some_an_s};
const struct_name_t name = {temp};
```

аналогичная ошибка.
Как проинициализировать данную структуру правильно в С++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Дело в том, что в С++ класс `another_struct_name` будет вложенным в класс `struct_name`, а не помещаться в глобальное пространство имен, как в С. Так что этот код уже не будет работать на выражении `const another_struct_name_t some_an_s`. Чтобы объявления можно было нормально использовать и в С, и в С++ вам надо избавиться от вложенных структур. А вот designated initializers можно оставить - они будут официально поддерживаться в С++20 и во многих компиляторах реализованы уже сейчас.

```
typedef struct another_struct_name another_struct_name_t;

struct another_struct_name
{
    int field1;
    int field2;
};

typedef struct struct_name struct_name_t;

struct struct_name
{
    another_struct_name_t const * field_name;
};

another_struct_name_t const some_an_s{.field1{3}, .field2{4}}; 
struct_name_t const name{.field_name{&some_an_s}};
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/gEndzz)

Comment: а зачем оставлять в программе то, что все еще не реализовано многих компиляторах?

Answer (score 6):

В С++ уже можно не дергаться со всеми этими `typedef`.

```
struct struct_name {
    struct another_struct_name {
        typefield1 field1;
        typefield2 field2;
    } const * field_name;
};

struct_name::another_struct_name some_an_s{value1, value2};

struct_name name{&some_an_s};
```

Примерно так (не компилировал за отсутствием `typefield`, например).

Только меня как минимум все же смущает создание объекта вложенной структуры за пределами охватывающего объекта... Не С++'ный подход.

Comment: Про `typedef` лучше вообще забыть, как страшный сон `using` - наше всё. И пусть вас не "смущает создание объекта вложенной структуры за пределами охватывающего объекта". Всё зависит от использования. Вложенная структура может быть приватной, объекты структуры - статическими или тут вообще а'ля Pimpl городится - всё очень даже С++'ный подход.